# numpy broadcasting in np.where

Tags: python, numpy

My question is, how do I broadcast values in `np.where` when using multiple conditions/outputs without having to rely on multiplication?

**Input:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test':range(0,10)})

   test
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     9
```

**Expected Output:**

```
   test  column1  column2
0     0        2        4
1     1        2        4
2     2        2        4
3     3        2        4
4     4        1        3
5     5        1        3
6     6        1        3
7     7        1        3
8     8        1        3
9     9        1        3
```

**My (working) code:**

```
mask  = df['test'] > 3
m_len = len(mask)

df['column1'], df['column2'] = np.where([mask, mask], [[1]*m_len, [3]*m_len], [[2]*m_len, [4]*m_len])
```

**Question:**

Normally `np.where()` accepts an array and a static value, for example:

```
np.where(mask, 1, 2) # where mask is a series
```

My expections where that if I now use this:

```
np.where([mask, mask], [1, 3], [2, 4])
```

it would broadcast this values.

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,10) (2,) (2,)
```

Is there a way to broadcast the values without having to use the `m_len` variable (as shown in my working code)?

Note: I know I can just use `np.where` multiple times, in multiple lines, but I want to solve it in that one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the shapes of the values you put in as `(2, 1)`, it will broadcast. Therefore, here is a way with `np.r_`:

```
df[["col1", "col2"]] = np.where(mask, np.r_["c", 1, 3], np.r_["c", 2, 4]).T
```

where the last `T` is needed since `np.where` will return `(2, -1)`-shaped array but pandas expects `(-1, 2)` for its two columns.

---

We can also give only one `mask` if both masks are the same since it will broadcast it too:

```
mask   ->  (10,)
values ->  (2, 1)
```

then

```
mask'  ->  (1, 10)
values ->  (2, 1)
```

and lastly

```
mask''  ->  (2, 10)
values' ->  (2, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but with the current approach I would need to create the columns beforehand, otherwise I get the error: `KeyError: "None of [Index(['col1', 'col2'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: @Andreas I don't get that error... Pandas version is 1.2.4, yours?

Comment: ahh, mine is: '0.25.1' I am not on my main pc right now. Thank you very much, that was very insightful.